# Как сделать такое самому?

Tags: php, localhost, tunnel

https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/

Что нужно для того что бы сделать подобное на своем сервере и как это сделать. Буду благодарен если поможете

Comment: Через два клика по ссылкам собственно есть и сервер https://github.com/localtunnel/server